# Why does setting theme programatically produce a different result than through the manifest?

Tags: android, themes, manifest

I'm curious if I'm doing something wrong or if this is just a bug...

When I set the theme for my activity in the manifest like so:

```
<activity
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
...>
```

The resulting activity has a semi opaque background through which I can see whatever Activity is next on the stack.

However, when I leave that command out of my manifest and do this right before I call `super.onCreate`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
   setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
   super.onCreate(b);
}
```

Which I believe is the proper way to set a theme programmatically on your Activity,
the content appears correctly in the center of the screen in a dialog box, but the background is entirely black.

Is there some *other theme I should be using? I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to set a translucent background programatically, through which you can see the screen below. If I remember correctly, [Theme_Translucent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme_Translucent) is used for the same (if you want to set it programmatically). Docs say that:

> **public static final int Theme_Translucent**
>
> Theme for translucent activities (on API level 10 and lower). That is, windows that allow you to see through them to the windows behind. This sets up the translucent flag and appropriate animations for your windows.

Also check out the following thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/vSZHsVWUCqk . This talks about exact same observation that you asked but the answers are still unsatisfactory.

Comment: You understand (mostly) correctly. Theme_Transucent is supposed to give me the transparent bg (though it appears not to work) but I'm actually trying to reproduce the exact behavior as the manifest example. I don't see such an option (both Dialog AND Translucent)